# fat arrow with objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to use a fat arrow with an object?

The following code prints out the contents of the array "test" in the console.

```
//With array
let test = [1, 2, 3, 4];
test.forEach(number => console.log(number));
```

I'm looking for a way to have the same output but with "test" being an object, not an array (like below). is there a (relatively) simple way of doing this?

```
//With object
let test = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}
test.forEach(number => console.log(number));
```

Comment: ES6 arrows are used to make arrow functions : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions Therefore, you can use them as you would with a usual function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: An arrow function is just a short hand, your issue here isn't the arrow function it's your loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a couple of ways to do this:

```
Object.keys(test).forEach(key => console.log(test[key]));
```

`Object.keys` is the oldest method, available since ES5.

However, as you're using ES6 method you can probably use newer methods:

```
Object.keys(test) // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
Object.values(test) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
Object.entries(test) // [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Array methods cannot be used on an object. Use `Object.keys` to get an array of object's keys, then use array method `forEach`

```js
let test = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}
Object.keys(test).forEach(number => console.log(test[number]));
```

Answer (score 1):

for array you can use `array.forEach()` and for object you need to use `Object.values(object).forEach()`  for values and `Object.keys(object).forEach()` for object keys. :D

```js
//With array
var test = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log("Array");
test.forEach(number => console.log(number));

console.log("Obejct");
//With object
var testObj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}
Object.values(testObj).forEach(number => console.log(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have following options

1) `Object.keys()`

```
test = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}

Object.keys(test).forEach(key => console.log(test[key]))
```

`Object.keys` returns an array of keys of the object it was called on.

2) `Object.values()`

```
test = {
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
   c: 3,
   d: 4
}

Object.values(test).forEach(value=> console.log(value))
```

`Object.values` Returns an array whose elements are the enumerable property values found on the object.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `Object.values()`

```
let test = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}
Object.values(test).forEach(number => console.log(number));
```